# multidimensional array for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a `for` loop such that the value `0` will change to `1` if either of the first two values matches the previous row in the array.

So for example, row 2 and row 3 will have the `0` value change to `1`, because row 1 has the values of `1` and `3`, which matches one of the two values in row 2 and 3.

Following such a case, all the value `0` will all change to `1` eventually (since row 4 will have values of row 2 and 3).

How can I create such a loop?

```
edgeArray=[[1,3,0],
            [1,4,0],
            [2,3,0],
            [2,4,0]]

for(var counter = 1; counter =< edgeArray.length; counter ++ {
    if current edgeArray[i][j][0]  && previous edgeArray[i][j][0] on same row && edgeArray[i][j][0] == 
then edgeArray[i][j][0] = edgeArray[i][j][1]
```

The end result to be

```
edgeArray=[[1,3,0],
        [1,4,1],
        [2,3,1],
        [2,4,1]]
```

Comment: Could you show what would the edgeArray result be?

Comment: Are you making changes concurrently? As in, are you modifying your array while iterating it so changes to the previous row affect the outcome for the next? Or are you using the values for the current row as-is, independent of change for the previous rows and creating a new array?

Comment: @nem It is actually linked to buttons. The values in the array is how the buttons are connected. i.e. Button 1 and button 3 are linked, Button 1 and Button 4  are linked etc. So when someone clicked on connecting buttons, the [0] value changes to [1]. In a sense, the first two row values will not change, only the last one will change.

Comment: Maybe you should split it up into 2 arrays?

Comment: @juvian, I added in the result.

Comment: why does first row change to 1 if there are no previous rows?

Comment: @juvian, you are right. Only from second row onwards it will change.

Comment: What is your goal with this? Know the connected buttons of the button you click?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand fully, but is this what you want??

```
for(var i = 1; i <= edgeArray.length; i ++) {
     // for each row (from second row onwards)
     if  (  edgeArray[i][0] == edgeArray[i-1][0]  
             // is the first val the same as prev row?
         || edgeArray[i][1] == edgeArray[i-1][1] 
             // or second val same as prev row?
         || edgeArray[i-1][2] == 1)  {
             // or is there already a '1' in 3rd col of prev row?
       edgeArray[i][2] = 1;
             // in that case change 3rd column to '1'
     }
 }
```

If you don't want to 'carry over' the previous `1`s to future rows, and you just want the 3rd column to reflect only the previous two rows, then just get rid of the third disjunctive condition in the if statement.

Comment: this throws an error, should be < edgeArray.length as I edited

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your requirement, but this results the way you want:

```
var edgeArray = [[1,3,0],
                 [1,4,0],
                 [2,3,0],
                 [2,4,0]];

var temp = [[],[]];

for(var i=0; i<edgeArray.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<2; j++){
        var found = temp[j].indexOf(edgeArray[i][j]);
        if(found > -1){
            edgeArray[i][2] = 1;
        }else{
            temp[j].push(edgeArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
    console.log(edgeArray[i].toString())
}
```